# Is the set of common-zeros of the systems of polynomials Zariski dense?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, zariski-topology

Let $K$ be an algebraically closed field of characteristic $0$.

Let $f: K^m \to K^m$ be a map defined by $f(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_m)=(f_1,f_2, \cdots,f_m)$ where $f_i \in K[x_1,x_2, \cdots, x_m]$. Let $Z$ denote the zeros of $f$ and its iterates $f^{\circ n}$ i.e., $$Z=\bigcup_n \{(x_1,x_2, \cdots,x_m) \in K^m~|~f^{\circ n}(x_1,x_2, \cdots,x_m)=0\}.$$

My question is-

> Is $Z$ a Zariski dense in $K^m$ ? or, When would $Z$ be Zariski dense in $K^m$ ?

---

If $m=1$, then the system reduces to just one polynomial $f \in K[x_1]$, and take unions of all the zeros of $f$ and its iterations. If we assume $f$ is of degree greater than 1 with distinct zeros, then the resulting zero set would be Zariski dense in $K$.

But I am not sure how to prove the case, when $m \geq 2$.

Comment: Why is your "observation" true? That would require $f_i(0, \dotsc, 0) = 0$, right? Also for $m = 1$, if $f_1 = x_1$, then $f_1(f_1) = x_1$ and so on, so $Z_k = \{0\}$ for all $k$.

Comment: @red_trumpet, yes I should have mentioned polynomials $f_i$ has zero constant coefficients. I am sorry for the 2nd part of your comment. Yes, I should exclude the trivial cases. Says, $f_1$ is $n$-degree ($n \geq 2$) polynomial with distinct  zeros

Comment: Your question can be restated as follows: Let $f$ be a polynomial map of $C^n$ to itself. Describe completely invariant proper algebraic subsets. Similarly to the situation in dimension 1, these are rare exceptions (what you call "trivial cases"). But listing all of them is not so trivial as in dimension 1. To begin with, the map $f$ can be bijective...

Comment: I believe that there is a solution in the literature for the case when $f$ extends to a map of $CP^m$. By the way, in this case, the infinite hyperplane is completely invariant, so if you consider preimages of any point in it they will not be Zariski dense.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko, I am interested in case where $Z$ will be Zariski dense. If $Z$ can not be contained in the union of finitely many curves, in that case, it will be Zariski dense.

Comment: For generic polynomials it will be dense. As I said in the first comment,  the cases when it is not dense are "exceptional". I gave two examples of these "exceptional" cases, but I am not sure that all of them have been listed.

Comment: Most of holomorphic dynamics in higher dimension studies two cases: a) bijective polynomial maps, or b) maps of $CP^m$. So I suppose that for general polynomial maps of $C^m$ it is not known.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko, do you mean by "generic polynomial" to be 1-variable polynomial ? For your last comment, it is not clear to me. Do you mean that if $f$ is bijective map or can be extended to $CP^m$, then my $Z$ will be Zariski dense ?

Comment: "Generic polynomial" is an element of a Z-dense set in the set of all polynomials. Both cases which I described are not generic. But all results which I am aware of study only these subsets. For these subsets, the preimages of some point are not dense.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko, ok thanks. can you find reference for the two cases you mentioned ?